# Backbone makes PUT request with id attribute

Tags: rest, backbone.js, put

When I try to save existing object like the below:

```
this.model.set('name', $('#district-name').val());
this.model.save();
```

Backbone makes PUT request to /api/districts/18 with data

```
id: 18
name: "qq3324"
```

but id is already in url and I don't want to send it in the body of request.

Comment: Why is that an issue? Can't you just ignore it on the server side?

Comment: On server side works validator, it's not pass extra params. And it's not depended from me.

Comment: `delete this.model.id` before doing `this.model.save()` this will cause backbone to send a post request to `'/api/districts'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Invoke `save` with the `patch` option

Call `model.save({ patch: true })` to make a `PATCH` request including only the changed 
properties - This affects only the current call to save, so you have to remember to pass the parameter for every call. Also, this mill result in a `PATCH` request, not in a `PUT` request.

### Write your own implementation of `Backbone.sync`

`Backbone.sync` is used by Backbone to communicate with a RESTful API. Overwrite the `Backbone.sync` method to exclude the ID when making a `PUT` request - This solution works globally. See the Backbone annotated source for an implementation of this method: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-130

### Overwrite the `toJSON` method of your model

`Backbone.sync` calls the `model.toJSON` method of the model, which is passed an options object (the same options object you give to the `model.save` function). You can overwrite this function to take a parameter which indicates that the ID should be excluded. This can work globally, if you always extend the `BaseModel` instead of `Backbone.Model`.

```
    var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        toJSON: function (options) {
            var data = _.clone(this.attributes);

            if (options.excludeId) {
                data = _.omit(data, 'id');
            }

            return data;
        }
    });

    var SomeModel = BaseModel.extend({});
    new SomeModel({ ... }).save({ excludeId: true });
```

### Or...

Or, just ignore the ID on the serverside.

Comment: This is just a proposal what might work - depending on your needs, the second or third option could suit you better than the first one. As you said you have no influence over the backend, the question to ask is "can my backend handle PATCH requests?"